# Not printing string from struct in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

Having a problem with print strings from structs in C...

```
typedef struct box{
    char *REF_OR_SYS; int num, x, y, w, h, o;
}BOX;

sscanf(str, "%s %d %d %d %d %d %d", &label, &refNum, &x, &y, &w, &h, &o);
BOX detect = {label, refNum, x, y, w, h, o};
printf("\nLABEL IS %s\n", detect.REF_OR_SYS); //Prints out the String correctly
                                              //(Either the word REF or SYS)
return detect;
```

When this is structure is passed to another structure, everything is displayed right EXCEPT for the string..

```
void printBox(BOX detect){
printf("Type: %s    Ref: %d    X: %d    Y: %d    W: %d    H: %d    O:%d\n", 
 detect.REF_OR_SYS, detect.num, detect.x, 
 detect.y, detect.w, detect.h, detect.o);
```

}

Am I missing something simple? REF_OR_SYS always prints out as ??_?

Comment: Is `label` a local variable to some other function?

Comment: `REF_OR_SYS` is a simple char* not an array of char, you have to allocate right memory to use your string.

Comment: label was a char label[4] declaration in that function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `strdup()` (usually available, if not use `malloc()`) to copy the string read into `label` by `sscanf()`:

```
detect.REF_OR_SYS = strdup(label);
```

as when that function returns `label` is out of scope and `REF_OR_SYS` will be a dangling pointer. Remember to `free()` it when no longer required.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks (it's been too long since I did dynamic memory allocation in C...)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `label` is a local character array, you are returning a pointer to function-local storage, which becomes an invalid pointer as the function exits.

You probably need

```
char REF_OR_SYS[32];
```

Or to dynamically allocate the string using `malloc()` (or `strdup()` if you have it).

Answer (score 1):

Try defining an array

```
typedef struct box{
    char REF_OR_SYS[20]; int num, x, y, w, h, o;
}BOX;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct box{
    char REF_OR_SYS[N]; int num, x, y, w, h, o;
} BOX;
```

where N is the required length (a constant) and

```
strcpy(detect.REF_OR_SYS, label);
```